# Use composite nodes in blender video sequence editor

Tags: node-editor, video-sequence-editor

Can you use composite nodes in blender video sequence editor?

As in, no 3d elements in your scene, working exclusively within the video editing screen layout?

I am currently using Blender 2.76 RC 3.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While you can't use composite nodes directly in VSE strips, you can setup the compositor with an image sequence or video file input without adding any elements from the 3d scene.

[image]

Then in the VSE you can add a scene strip which gets the composited render results, so you can mix in audio and use any VSE specific features. You can also setup multiple scenes with different composite nodes and join them all in the VSE.

[image]

Comment: When I add Scene strip to VSE, it shows the cube (the default 3D scene) only.

Comment: When rendering or in the VSE preview? If the render isn't right check the [sequencer is enabled here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/post_process/panel.html), if the preview is wrong then change the [sequencer preview shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/vse/preview/properties.html) (press N) to rendered.

Comment: [Sequencer is enabled here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/post_process/panel.html). Older link point to the dev branch of the docs, that's is 2.80 now.

Comment: [Sequence preview shading there](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/vse/preview/properties.html)

Comment: When I add a scene strip, how do I find it in the input node? What is the node on the left in the first image? You have to add the scene strip above the film layer?

Comment: @MicroMachine the first image is the compositor, you add an image input node and select the video file, then you can add a scene strip in the vse to get the end result of the composite nodes.

Comment: Just a quick note regarding **sambler**'s answer. If you end up seeing the default cube in the "Video Sequence Editor" backdrop, here's a quick fix: Assuming you're using a new ".blend" file for compositing, simply delete all objects from the scene in "3D View" and your image sequence (or movie clip) should appear in its place (tested in 2.79B, at least). Hope this helps any passersby! Peace and God bless!

Comment: It's year 2024. Is the "create new scene for each chroma keyed file" still the state of art for Blender video editor?

Answer (score 3):

No.  However, there are modifiers and effects that can be added to the VSE such as glow and colour changes etc. that can be applied to strips in the sequencer.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, and ***that*** is the way to go for unlimited video tweaking. Follow this tutorial to make Blender VSE with compositor and keyframe-based node editor, along with standards strip effects, realtime.

2.79 : https://youtu.be/chIdSAR_8NY

2.80 : https://youtu.be/g1ZkPSLqGnU

https://github.com/cgvirus/Blender-Compositor-Disc-Cache-Realtime-Preview-Addon