# blender viewer node doesn't play smoothly

Tags: compositing-nodes

Why is the viewer node in the compositor mode so slow in blender? It seems as if it is only capable of refreshing single frames, but not the whole video.

Is there a way speed up the process?

**edit1, explanation:**

I'm working on a very short chromakey clip. In order to preview the results I either have to step very quickly through the frame-timeline, or render the final result to a file. Latter option is also very slow, therefore I would rather prefer a quicker preview option.

Comment: You could send your render scene data / image or other files to VSE and preview clip from there; note that it might be slow too.

Comment: thx for the answer. I'm new to blender, so how can this be done?

Comment: It depends on what are going to do; see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15440/1245 for rendering scene from VSE with OpenGL (faster / less effects, for previewing), this - http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39396/1245 for using workaround for adding composite nodes to VSE result; for simple "as-is" preview add *Scene* clip in VSE and choose which mode to render it in while previewing. See [Video Sequence Editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/pt/editors/sequencer/introduction.html) in manual.

Comment: thx for the links, but both didn't help really much.running the first solution ("opengl render active viewport") lets the screen stay black. the latter solution doesn't work at all...