# Can I Denoise pre-rendered footage?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, denoise

I have a reasonably lengthy sequence of PNG's which I rendered while I was away from my machine. To my chagrin, I returned to find that I neglected to enable denoising data at render-time!

I am left with a noisy image sequence (.png) with minor, but noticeable fireflies.

[image]

Is it possible to denoise footage that has already been rendered in Blender?

I have tried repairing my footage via inputting the .png sequence into the Blender VSE, and using the denoising data-node in the compositor - but it does not recognize it as a proper render string, or as render data! Thus it will not be accessed via the compositor.

Comment: You can run denoising on the images, but the results probably won't be what you expect because the denoiser expects additional data (sample counts and such).  This is what you enable with that check box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about the VSE, but yes, the *Denoise* node in the *Compositor* can denoise already rendered image sequences, which means you can import a sequence there, plug it in the *Composite* output and plug a *Denoise* node inbetween.

Just note: it doesn't work very well on let's say noisy images from cameras etc. where the noise is maybe even a bit blurred. It has to be the crisp, "one-pixel-noise" from a Blender render to work best.

[image: setup]

Before denoising:

[image: noisy]

After denoising:

[image: denoised]

Comment: Is the Red node titled "####" an Image Sequence node? (Thank you for your speedy reply!)

Comment: @PierreDucos That's right, it's an _Image Sequence_ node.

Comment: I have just one more question - When I render the image sequence, it isn't using our lovely compositing nodes! What do I do to enable the compositor at render time? I am rendering from the VSE.

Comment: I found this thread, for anyone looking to render composite nodes from the VSE! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39396/use-composite-nodes-in-blender-video-sequence-editor

Comment: @PierreDucos Sorry, was a bit late for me to answer, but well, you found a way. I didn't know you needed to render it from the VSE, because just for denoising this wouldn't be necessary. But in the _Compositor_ you should mute or delete the _Render Layer_ so that the scene isn't complerely rendered although you just want the image sequence. Maybe I should add this to the answer.

Comment: That would be good! In the end, I created two scenes, enabled rendering from the VSE in BOTH scenes, added my PNG sequence in BOTH scenes, added a "scene" strip in BOTH scenes (each strip referencing the opposite scene - a scene can't reference itself!) and THEN, once the Compositor could be recognized (via the Scene strip in the VSE, which DOES render with composite passes) I rendered - and it worked! (Peachy!) This thread explains this process in further detail: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39396/use-composite-nodes-in-blender-video-sequence-editor